Getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django' while deploying Django on uWSGI server, while uWSGI server is running on Cygwin on Windows OS
I have installed Cygwin on Windows 10 and installed following packages

gcc-core (version 11.0.4-1, under Devel category )
gcc-g++ (version 11.0.4-1, under Devel category )
libintl-devel (version 0.22.4-1, under Text category )
gettext-devel (version 0.22.4-1, under Text category )
python3-devel (version 3.9.16-1, under Python category )
python38-devel (version 3.9.16-1, under Python category )

And I have installed uWSGI version 2.0.25.1 in Cygwin, to deploy a django application.
The wsgi.py file of the Django application looks like
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'PrateekGupta.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()

The config file for uWSGI looks like
[uwsgi]
chdir = P:/Portfolio/Django
module = PrateekGupta.wsgi:application
pythonpath = /home/PrateekGupta/virtual_environment/Scripts/python
master = True
pidfile = /tmp/project-master.pid
vacuum = True
max-requests = 5000
daemonize = /var/log/Portfolio.log
http-socket = 127.0.0.1:8000
buffer-size = 65536

I have activated the Virtual Environment and have installed python and django in it. The response of the
pip list

command is
Package           Version
----------------- -------
asgiref           3.8.1
Django            5.0.6
pillow            10.3.0
pip               21.3.1
PyJWT             2.8.0
setuptools        58.4.0
sqlparse          0.5.0
typing_extensions 4.11.0
tzdata            2024.1
wheel             0.37.0

But still whenever I run the uwsgi server with the command
uwsgi --ini portfolio-uwsgi.ini

In the log file I'm getting the error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/cygdrive/p/Portfolio/Django/./PrateekGupta/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
    from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

In the uWSGI config file also I have added the pythonpath for the python of the Virtual Environment but still getting the same error.
Also, I have done same config on EC2 instance and its working absolutely fine but its not working when running on Windows via Cygwin.
